# iOS "Exploding image" animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm looking for some help/tips/pointers in creating a specific iOS animation and how it works. The type of animation I'm looking to create is similar to below, in particular the transition, what I've (probably incorrectly) termed as an "exploding image":

[image: Exploding image]

The order of the animation appears to be:

- Image scale is reduced, I know how to animate this using CGAffineTransform.
- The top view is split into two along a line
- The two sections in the top view are animated out

I don't know if my assumptions are correct? And I haven't found/know any resources in how to create the "split view" animation.

(I don't think the scale of the image is actually enlarged but it does have that appearance)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for something that's similar to the twitter intro I would suggest you check this

https://github.com/callumboddy/CBZSplashView

Comment: Thanks @Vig, that's what I'm exactly after.